# How to make a header the width of the entire page

Tags: html, css, angular, header

I'm trying to figure out how to make the width of a header across the entire page. I want to do that and push the notifications section down.  It currently cuts off as shown in the image below:

**html**

```
  <header>
    <div>
      <app-ao-logo>

      </app-ao-logo>
   </div>
  </header>
```

I updated css from this:

**css**

```
 header {
   margin:auto;
 }
```

to this:

```
header {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

This stretches the header but the Notifications section is not pushed down.

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to use CSS to set the width of the element relative to page width:

```css
header {
  /* ... */
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: This partially works. It stretches across but doesn't push the Notifications section down. If that makes sense.

Comment: Like the notifications section is overlapping with the header?  Would be helpful to edit your question and include more of your code so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: You could add a `margin-top: 100px` or something to your notfications section but would need more clarity on your layout to do something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend using grid
This website has a bunch examples for you to take a look at:
https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

Comment: I do agree regarding grids, it would help you build to build your desired look pretty quickly. But you can also consider setting width 100% for you header container, and set logo width too, so that it don't stretch up in the entire container.